# Scraper stopped scraping

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping

I ran scraping ops this morning:

The scraper runs through list fine, but just keeps saying "skipped" as per code.
I have checked a few and confirmed the information i require is on the website.

I have pulled my code apart piece by piece but cannot find any changes - I've even gone back to a vanilla version of my code to see and still no luck.

Could someone please run this and see what I am missing as I am going insane!

Target website https://www.realestate.com.au/property/12-buckingham-dr-werribee-vic-3030

Code:

```
import requests
import csv
from lxml import html

text2search = '''<p class="property-value__title">
      RECENTLY SOLD
    </p>'''

quote_page = ["https://www.realestate.com.au/property/12-buckingham-dr-werribee-vic-3030"]

with open('index333.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

    for index, url in enumerate(quote_page):
        page = requests.get(url)

        if text2search in page.text:
            tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

            (title,) = (x.text_content() for x in tree.xpath('//title'))
            (price,) = (x.text_content() for x in tree.xpath('//div[@class="property-value__price"]'))
            (sold,) = (x.text_content().strip() for x in tree.xpath('//p[@class="property-value__agent"]'))

            writer.writerow([url, title, price, sold])
        else:
            writer.writerow([url, 'skipped'])
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this is neither a free design/coding nor debugging service, tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can help solve [certain problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's **your** job to **[put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** on the subject in the first place, including elementary **[(re)search](https://google.com/)**.

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski. Thankyou for your response. I have done more than elementary research. I have pulled the code to pieces, gone back to a vanilla version of the code without the extra features that I have added over the last 3 months. I have conducted IP tests, checked google, SO, LP@ Reddit, Tried running it on a different PC. I was asking the SO community for help, not to fix my problems for me.

Comment: since `skipped` is show when `if text2search in page.text:` fails, this means that you should check if what you are looking for is still there. Blind assumption that remote data remains intact is unjustified.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski - You were 100 percent correct. There was additional whitespace entered into the html. Thank you for assisting.

Comment: @james2086 I just counted diff whitespace as well... so you got it? A tip: since "property-value__title" appears only once, do you need the extra stuff that seems to make it more prone to breakage?

Comment: btw, not sure why @marcin-orlowski had a problem with your question, seems to me you hit #1 on his referenced list just right: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")..."

Comment: @MT - Thanks, yes I found the white space, the code is working fine again.
In regards to " do you need the extra stuff that seems to make it more prone to breakage?", No i have removed alot of this code over the last few months and added some other features, this was the very original code that I built, I figured i should go back to the start & also not post 200 lines of code.

Comment: @MT I explained in 3rd comment. This is basic code really if if `else` is executed then you know where to look for why it is so.

Comment: James, since you solved it, you should answer your own question and mark it as accepted so it won't show as unsolved. I think you'll get points for that as well, if you care.

Comment: @MT - Thankyou, I have done exactly that.

Comment: I think you got close. It may seem odd since you are answering your own question but since there is no check mark I think there is one more step for you. You have suggested an answer but you have yet to accept it. Try that. Also, if you appreciate our help you can click the up triangle next to our answers to mark as helpful. We will get points for that. Not really a big deal, but nice. You might go through some of your previous questions and chose an accepted answer. The poster will get points for that as well.

Comment: @MT - Thank you, I'm more than happy to give back to the people who have helped me :). I will go through now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a change in the HTML code that introduced an additional white space.
This stopped the *text2search in page.text:* from running.

Thanks to @MarcinOrlowski for pointing me in the right direction

Thanks to advice from @MT - the code has been shortened to lessen the chances of this occurring again.